# Restrictions on $\mathbf{U}$ in $\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{U}\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{U}\mathbf{a}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have two complex vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ and a complex unitary matrix $\mathbf{U}$. Under what conditions on $\mathbf{U}$ will the following equation hold:

$$\vec{A}^T \mathbf{U}\vec{B}=\vec{B}^T\mathbf{U}\vec{A} $$

This is important to understand restrictions on certain counter-propagating optical beams. In this specific case, $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ are $3\times1$ matrices and $\mathbf{U}$ is a unitary $3\times3$ matrix. The following clearly holds: $$\mathbf U = [[\pm 1, 0 ,0];[0,\pm 1,0];[0,0,\pm 1]]. $$ Is there a more general case?

**Addendum I**

The $T$ indicates normal transpose such that we could equally write, in the 3-D case:

$$\vec{A}\cdot \mathbf{U}\vec{B}=\vec{B}\cdot\mathbf{U}\vec{A} ,$$

where $\cdot$ indicates dot product.

Comment: Should $T$ here be the ordinary transpose, or the conjugate-transpose?

Comment: For complex vectors, it is traditional to define the dot product by
$$
(x_1,x_2,x_3) \cdot (y_1,y_2,y_3) = 
x_1 \overline{y_1}+
x_2 \overline{y_2}+
x_3 \overline{y_3}
$$
hence my confusion.

Comment: What a strange convention. That means the dot product is no longer commutative.

Comment: Indeed.  What we now have is something "[sesquilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form)".  The advantage of this convention is that $\vec x \cdot \vec x$ is always a positive real number, so that we can derive a norm on $\Bbb C^n$ from the inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will denote the vectors as $a$ and $b$, and the matrix as $U$.  I assume that $T$ refers to the transpose rather than the adjoint (AKA conjugate-transpose). Suppose that 
$$
a^TUb = b^TUa
$$
for every $a$ and $b$.  Setting $a = e_j$ and $b = e_k$ (where $e_1,\dots,e_n$ are the standard basis vectors), we find
$$
U_{jk} = U_{kj}
$$
So that $U$ must be symmetric.  In fact, for any symmetric matrix, we have
$$
(a^TUb)^T = b^TU^Ta = b^TUa
$$
So that the symmetry of $U$ is a necessary and sufficient condition.

---

As a counterexample in your $3 \times 3$ cases, consider the matrix
$$
U = 
\pmatrix{
1&0&0\\
0&1/\sqrt 2 & 1/\sqrt 2\\
0&1/\sqrt 2 & -1/\sqrt 2
}
$$

---

If you mean the conjugate transpose: setting $a = e_j$ and $b = ie_k$, we get
$$
a^*Ub = b^*Ua \implies\\
U_{jk} = -U_{kj}
$$
So that $U$ would have to be both symmetric and anti-symmetric, so that $U = 0$.